# how to remove the first level of nested list structure?

Tags: python-3.x, list

What my list looks like:

```
my_list = [  [[1, 'a'],[1, 'b']],  [[2, 'a']],  [[3, 'a'],[3, 'b'],[3, 'c']]  ]
```

My ideal list:

```
my_list = [ [1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'a'], [3, 'a'], [3, 'b'], [3, 'c'] ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i hope to keep the [int, char] structure, but I want to get rid of the extra nesting in my_list

Answer (score 1):

just iterate with list comprehension and get the first one:

```
my_list = [l for li in my_list for l in li]
```

Output:

```
[ [1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'a'], [3, 'a'], [3, 'b'], [3, 'c'] ]
```

Comment: This is not correct, check again the nesting in the question.

Comment: @costaparas Did the recent edit fix your concerns? The result appears correct in my tests.

Comment: Ah I see you removed the `map` version. List comprehension is right now. But `itertools` is much simpler for this anyway, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/14722562) in the dupe.